# Are there any superheroes in DC that break the fourth wall?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, dc-animated-universe

Deadpool is the ultimate fourth wall breaker and we all know that.

But do DC have some or any superheroes that break the fourth wall?

Not some random fourth wall breaks but someone who has a habit of doing so...

Comment: “Deadpool is the ultimate fourth wall breaker and we all know that.” *[citation needed]*

Comment: In college, I played a GURPS campaign once that, at one point, had all of our characters stuck in a comic book.  We couldn't speak (although we COULD communicated, once one of us thought of drawing Speech bubbles on paper), and the eventual trick that got us out (breaking the 4th wall to the GM, via 'action' bubbles (well, blocks, really) - I believe I used something along the lines of '*character name* grabs the frame of the cartoon, and vaults out, into the real world') came to us via a clue from DC's Ambush Bug, who is well known for breaking the fourth wall.

Comment: [Ambush Bug](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Ambush_Bug) is the worst offender I know of in the DC universe.

Comment: Dead-who?  She-Hulk was doing it before Deadpool even existed!

Comment: Does hocking Hostess fruit pies count? Because then, Batman and Robin TOTALLY.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite “Deadpool is the ultimate fourth wall breaker and we all know that.” [It is known].

Comment: @Liesmith: this ain’t Essos son! We got standards around here!

Comment: Golden age comics couldn't go 5 minutes without breaking the 4th wall, in general. Batman was constantly asking people to enlist, donate scrap metal to the war cause, etc. The examples are endless.

Comment: I keep thinking that Booster Gold would be a prime candidate for breaking the wall, but I might be mis-remembering because of his in-milieu self marketing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes they do.

As per [http://dc.wikia.com/](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Fourth_Wall)

> In the Golden and Silver Age era of DC comics, such characters routinely broke the Fourth Wall, usually as a convenience for introducing a story. After the Crisis on Infinite Earths, comic storytelling took a more mature turn, and few characters demonstrated this ability.
>
> **DC Characters known to break the Fourth Wall**
>
> - Abel
> - Ambush Bug
> - Animal Man
> - Black Hand
> - Cain
> - Death
> - Destiny
> - Doctor Thirteen
> - Eve
> - Joker
> - Kindly Ones
> - Lobo
> - Lucien
> - Madame Xanadu
> - Marie Leeds-Thirteen
> - Merryman (Myron Victor)
> - Mister Mxyzptlk (New Earth)
> - Miss America (Joan Dale)
> - Phantom Stranger
> - Odd Man (Clay Stoner)

There are few <strike>many</strike> instances of breaking the fourth wall in [DCAU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_animated_universe). Refer [here](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_characters_that_have_broken_the_fourth_wall) for the list of instances.

One of the famous ones is from Batman: The Animated Series, "Joker's Favor", where the Joker addresses audience (at 13:38):

Until now, [DCEU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Extended_Universe) seems too serious for breaking the fourth wall.

Comment: Your video link is dead

Comment: @Valorum can't find any replacement yet.

Comment: Was the "Joker's Favor" scene in any of these YouTube videos? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Un6q-9g64M https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdXpoDVcbDo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obj5KNcoQfo

Answer (score 7):

### In the DC Universe, The Joker is the chief 4th wall breaker.

In Batman: The Animated Series and Justice League, The Joker addresses the audience, [usually as though they were an audience.](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_characters_that_have_broken_the_fourth_wall)

In the comics, the Joker breaks the fourth wall in much the same way, addressing the viewer directly. However, given the format, there are other ways to break the fourth wall...
[image: BTFW]
<sub>(source: [comicvine.com](https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/6/64770/1297533-jokerburgers.jpg))</sub>

Comment: He doesn’t seem to be making any sense in this strip… “What is everybody stops eating fish? I hadn’t thought of that. What if they all conspire against me, leave my Joker-fish in the sea? But no—that would never work. The _vegetarians_ wouldn’t go along!” — Eh, wha? Vegetarians wouldn’t go along with others not eating fish? Why not? \*confuzzled\*

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The Joker doesn't *need* to make sense. What's important is that he throws back the horns through the page.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: That, and the only context we have for his train of thought in this "conversation" is this one page. We have no idea what was on the pages before it, and whatever is on those earlier pages doesn't really have any bearing on this answer. If you're hoping to make sense of it, it's probably time to go pick up a comic book.

Comment: Yes, I’m aware of that. I was merely commenting on the fact that what he was saying appears to be nonsense. Then again, it _is_ the Joker…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Some people who call themselves vegetarians are actually more accurately described as pescetarians. Even some dictionaries include an exception for fish in their definition of vegetarian. Presumably that's the intended reading here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Put more plainly: The idea is that vegetarians eat fish instead of meat and thus they wouldn't be able to switch to meat and would have to keep eating the Joker's fish.

Comment: Isn't this the one where Joker dumps "joker chemicals" into the sea making "joker fish". People eat the fish and get a permanent Joker smile. Also, this appears to be him talking to himself.

Comment: I am not sure if Joker is actually breaking the fourth wall here. He is speaking to an audience which doesn't exist in the context of the comic, but this rather seems to be an imaginary audience in his head, not the audience holding the comic book.

Comment: @GorchestopherH Last panel. Literally breaking the fourth wall.
And the audience *never* exists in the context of the comic, which is why it's called the Fourth Wall. To the comic characters, Joker's talking to himself - or a wall. To the audience, he's talking to them.

Comment: @Philipp See the above.

Comment: @Axelrod Ah... I see, I was thrown off by all the comments talking about how the Joker isn't making any sense.

Answer (score 7):

Probably the most famous case of 4th wall breaking in DC Comics:
[image]

Comment: DC covers aren't always supposed to be taken at canon value, though.

Comment: The cover seems to imply that this continues in the rest of the comic, though.  I'm not sure whether that's the case or not.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you'd quite call it 'breaking the fourth wall' but in her Rebirth solo title Harley Quinn has shown awareness (in conversation with other characters) that she's in a comic strip.

[image]
<sup><sub>[**Harley Quinn (2016) #04**](http://www.dccomics.com/comics/harley-quinn-2016/harley-quinn-4)</sub></sup>

Comment: Can you offer a panel that shows her breaking the fourth wall?

Comment: I can't find the panel online, but in Harley Quinn Rebirth #4, page 15 top panel, Harley says _"Hey! Where did that tree come from?"_ Another character replies _"Don't be a smart-***. Trees do grow in Mumbai, you know!"_ Harley replies _"I just thought the artist put it there fer no reason. It ain't even in the script!"_ (which leads the second character to ask her what the **** she's talking about).